# Kali 1.1.0 - issue with bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, libpq, metasploit

When trying to run `pattern_create.rb` I get an error message that `rake-10.4.2` is missing and I need to run bundle install.

Running bundle install it run's until Installing `pg` (0.18.1) with native extensions  results in an error:

> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

I was told that:

> You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
>   You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.

I've tried the following: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1`, then     `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2` and `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

The last instruction ends with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libpq-dev : 
     Depends: libpq5 (= 9.1.14-0+deb7u1) but 9.1.15-0+deb7u1 is to be installed
     Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Running `sudo bundle install` again after that still results in the same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not actually solving why bundle install did not work, I found this on Stackoverflow: [Metasploit induction of bundle and rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303935/metasploit-induction-of-bundle-and-rake)

The solution from Aj and Mahendra let me run `pattern_create.rb`.